# GKE user PermissionDenied to write to metric container.googleapis.com/internal/node/inodes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm create GKE version 1.12.8-gke.10, then i seen these log in Google Logging:

- `Error while sending request to Stackdriver rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = User xxx does not have permission to write to metric container.googleapis.com/internal/node/inodes`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you having any trouble in creating a GKE cluster(version:1.12.8-gke.10)? If not, the the error itself seems like a permission issue connected with the your cluster's service account while writing data to Stackdriver. Please use [this troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/observing?hl=de#troubleshooting) guide. Your service account might be missing necessary roles mentioned there.

Comment: Thank for your help me - @halfer , i'm trying set these permission to service account:  Logs Writer, Monitoring Metric Writer, Stackdriver Resource Metadata Writer. But the error is still not fixed!

Comment: ^ That is probably best for @Digil.

Comment: oh, sorry! @half. I was confused!

Comment: Please do open a [defect report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) using Google Cloud Platform issue tracker. While opening the report, try to include all the details including reproduction steps, screenshots(if any), documents you have followed, etc..

Comment: Thank @Digil, I have reported this error to Google and we are talking about it!

Comment: As per the [latest response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139769936#comment6) in the issue-tracker, it does seems like this was an issue connected GKE and it's been resolved now.